# Possible to pass constant value to function parameter?

Tags: java, function, variables, optimization, parameters

I'm a computer science student, and I was studying homework earlier last night. I stumbled upon a function in my book that I thought was redundant, but upon further inspection I have gotten rather "confused"

```
public int refundBalance() {
  int amountToRefund = balance;
  balance = 0;
  return amountToRefund;
}
```

As I looked at this, I thought that having to create a new local variable to store and pass data around was rather redundant, so I thought up this:

```
refundBalance(balance);
public int refundBalance(int amount) {
  balance = 0;
  return amount;
}
```

But obviously, i'm just "trading lines".

**Question:** Is there any way to **always** pass the same parameter to a function, without having to pass the value on call?

**Optional Question**: How would/could you optimize this function? (If even possible)

Thanks all <3 (P.S. this is not a homework assignment, it's just basic curiosity.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, so just to make sure: in your first example, is `balance` an instance variable (that is, a field) of the class where `refundBalance()` is declared?  How is your `refundBalance(int amount)` intended to be used?  Since `amount` is returned unchanged, the only effect of calling `refundBalance()` is to set `balance` to zero.  Also, your wording of "pass the same parameter" is unclear: are you talking about passing the same *value* (in which case, just hardcode it), or the same *variable* (in which you'll need to encapsulate it in some kind of closure)?

Comment: If you always pass the same parameter to a function, why wont you just declare it inside the function ?

Comment: @DanielPryden The context of the function isn't really an issue. It's goal is basicly your question: To save balance and then set it to zero, returning the saved balance when done. I was thinking about passing the same _variable_ , yes. I thought about default parameters, but Java doesn't support that unless you overload the method... But my idea was to set the default parameter as the _variable_ balance.

Comment: @yackyackyack: But the `balance` *variable* is a field on the current object... so it **is** implicitly a parameter to the method. There's no point in passing it along as an argument, since the method always has access to its containing object's state.  In Java, there are only three kinds of variables: *local* variables in a method, which are only in scope in the body of that method, *instance* variables that are associated with a specific object instance, and *static* variables that are associated with a class (although you probably should avoid that last kind!).

Comment: @yackyackyack: Also, your question about optimization seems very premature.  What are you trying to optimize for: less code, clearer code, code that compiles into the smallest amount of bytecode, code that uses the least memory at runtime, code that executes in the least amount of time, etc.?  Any or all of those are valid goals to optimize for, and the appropriate one(s) to select depend entirely on the circumstances of your application.  The tiny amount of code you've posted in your question is unlikely to yield substantial improvements in any of those categories, however.

Comment: @DanielPryden The thing is though: How would you save balance, set it to zero and return it without using parameters **nor** a contemporary local variable? Only way I could think of was through a parameter, and that was the catalyst for my question.

Comment: @DanielPryden Good point. It was probably waaaay to premature. I usually think of optimization very broadly, so to me and optimization would basicly have been anything.

Comment: @yackyackyack: As I just posted as a reply to one of your comments below, there is no reason to think that the use of a temporary local variable will have any effect on performance whatsoever.  If anything, a method parameter will have *more* overhead, since it involves setting up a stack frame, pushing the argument, etc.  This kind of micro-optimization is extremely unlikely to be worthwhile; the JIT will do a much better job at this than you can.  Instead, concentrate on making your code *clear* and *readable*, and your fellow programmers will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is a fine, standard object oriented practice.

There is a state, a private field `balance`, which you can only modify by public methods, ensuring that accountancy is safe.

Now for doing the function without local variable:

```
public int refundBalance() {
    try {
        return balance;
    } finally {
        balance = 0;
    }
}
```

This *should* do:

- push value of balance
- store 0 into balance
- return

Comment: Of course we both know how much our colleagues will love such code.

Comment: I'm not doubting the code. I just like to see if there is a way to "hack" the language for ridiculous optimization :)

Comment: @yackyackyack: What kind of "ridiculous optimization" are you hoping for?  It is *extremely* unlikely that there is any way to optimize that first version of the method.  Remember that the compiler and JIT are free to do all kinds of optimizations, including eliding the allocation of a stack slot for a local variable if it can be stored in a register instead.  You're not going to get any faster than that.

Comment: @yackyack 101 for compiler optimizations: The most legible, idiomatic code will almost always produce the best object code. I wouldn't count on the JIT to produce good code for the try/finally example - if it does, that's coincidence because you can be pretty certain that no compiler test suite will contain such code. (if we're talking about optimization wrt "better readable" or "shorter" - well it fails in both cases anyhow)

Comment: Once threadsafety is a concern, this isn't even about premature optimization... the code above would be incorrect without proper synchronization, and it just so happens that you can get proper synchronization with a one liner :-). But I definitely agree with what everyone has been saying about optimization and encapsulation and such.

Comment: @Tom the original code is not threadsafe too. Should have been an AtomicInteger.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes I know it wasn't :-)... that is why I gave the answer I did below :-).

Answer (score 2):

In reality, you actually probably want to access the balance atomically and protect it from multiple threads having access. If that's the case, you can use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to do this in one shot via `getAndSet`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

private final AtomicInteger balance = new AtomicInteger();

public int refundBalance() {
  return balance.getAndSet(0);
}
```

This is actually what I'd recommend on top of using `synchronized` on the method and writing it as you have above. It also happens to be one line :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean via a default parameter, then no. Since refundBalance is a public method and the class that encloses it stores the balance variable, it wouldn't make sense for an outside object to be able to determine the amount to refund - you could provide a refundAmount method with an amount parameter if you wanted that functionality.

As for the optional question, I think that trying to optimize that function is pointless - it's fine as it is and you wouldn't gain any performance increase.

Comment: Again, it is all out of curiosity to see if someone could come up with some sort of optimization (if it exists) for this. It's not even a problem, mind you. More of a "mind game". But yes, you're answer did provide me with good insight. Thank you.